# Query and Dataset Syntax Peculiarities

Tags: dataset, query

## Question

Can someone please explain to me the syntax of `Query` and why its behavior is so befuddling to me at the moment?

I am going to go through a few simple examples to demonstrate my confusion.

## Example

Let's take the `List` of `Associations` from the `Query` documentation (and modify it slightly)

```
d1 = Dataset@{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", ""]|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", ""]|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> "Bad Value"|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> Missing|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}
```

[image]

For a sanity check, let's run the first example from the documentation:

[image]

Great. That works. What about `DeleteDuplicates`, which should delete anything with the `Head` `Missing`.

[image]

Ok that doesn't work. Well maybe these values do not have the `Head` `Missing`?

[image]

Huh... that worked! Now what if I just swap `Head` for `DeleteMissing`?

[image]

What just happened?

Maybe it is the `#c`?

[image]

Nope... Forcing the Notebook to rearrange this dataset (where `a` is the output from above)

[image]

Ok... let's try `Select` in a variety of forms:

```
Query[All, Select[Head@#c == List] &]@d1
d1[All, Select[#c == {2, 3}] &]
Select[d1, #c == {2, 3} &]
```

[image]

only the last one works...

What about the same thing with `DeleteCases`?

```
Query[All, DeleteCases[Head@#c == List] &]@d1
d1[All, DeleteCases[#c == {2, 3}] &]
DeleteCases[d1, #c == {2, 3} &]
```

[image]

Well now even the third form isn't working...

What is going on?

## Documentation

[`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)
[`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)
[`DeleteMissing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html)
[`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html?q=Select)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through it blow-by-blow...

## Query[DeleteMissing] @ d1

This will apply `DeleteMissing` to the list of associations.  The documentation says:

> DeleteMissing[*list*]
>       drops elements with head *Missing* from a list.

All of the elements of the list have head `Association`, so this operation is a no-op.

## d1[All, #c &, Head]

This works as advertised, showing the heads of the values associated with the key *c* in each association.

## d1[All, #c &, DeleteMissing]

This asks to delete missing elements from the lists that appear as values associated with the key *c* in each association.  Most of the *c* values are not lists.  The error that appears reflects that fact.

## Query[All, DeleteMissing] @ d1

This asks to delete from each association in the list any key/value pairs whose value has the head `Missing`.  If we look at the `Normal` form of the result we find that this is what happened:

```
d1[All, DeleteMissing] // Normal

(* { <|a->1, b->x|>
   , <|a->2, b->y, c->{2,3}|>
   , <|a->3, b->z|>
   , <|a->4, b->x, c->Bad Value|>
   , <|a->5, b->y, c->Missing|>
   , <|a->6, b->z, c->{}|>
   }
*)
```

As noted in the question, the `Dataset` visualization of this result is broken (v11) due to incorrect inferred metadata, and it can be fixed by rededucing the metadata.

Note that the result still contains the association with the pair `c->Missing`.  This is because `DeleteMissing` only considers values whose *head* is `Missing`, i.e. expressions of the form `Missing[...]`.  The raw symbol `Missing` is left untouched.  If we wish to delete pairs whose values are either form, we can write:

```
Query[All, DeleteCases[_Missing | Missing]] @ d1
```

This exhibits the same visualization bug as the original expression.

## Query[All, Select[Head@#c == List] &]@d1

This one is operating upon the wrong level -- the `Select` should be applied to the association list, not to each association individually.  Also, the `&` is misplaced:

```
Query[Select[Head@#c == List &]]@d1
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

As to the placement of `&`, note that `Select` requires a function as its argument.  Since we want to use a pure function, that means the expression should be of the form `Select[...&]` rather than `Select[...]&`.  Furthermore, since `Select[...]` is a function in its own right, `Select[...]&` defines a pure function that returns a function.

If we correct the `&` placement in the original expression, we can use `Normal` to see how the query is interpreted:

```
Query[All, Select[Head@#c == List] &] // Normal

(* Map[Select[Head[#c] == List] &] *)
```

From this expanded form, we can see that the query is attempting to map the `Select` across the associations.

For more information about levels and operators in queries, see [(98181)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98193/142) or [(89080)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89080/142).

## d1[All, Select[#c == {2, 3} &]]

Same problem, should be `d1[Select[#c == {2, 3} &]]`.

## Select[d1, #c == {2, 3} &]

As noted, works.

## Query[All, DeleteCases[Head@#c == List] &]@d1

The same error again but in addition `DeleteCases` requires a pattern -- not a function like `Select`:

```
Query[DeleteCases[_?(Head@#c == List &)]]@d1
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

## d1[All, DeleteCases[#c == {2, 3}] &]

Same again, should be `d1[DeleteCases[_?(#c == {2, 3} &)]]`.

## DeleteCases[d1, #c == {2, 3} &]

Same again, should be `DeleteCases[d1, _?(#c == {2, 3} &)]`.

Comment: thank you for this answer.  I have  few follow up questions: `Query[All, DeleteMissing] @ d1` still has one `c->Missing` why? Could you maybe elaborate on the depth for `Query`? and while this is not directly related, the where the end definition for a pure function needs to go, especially if there might be nested pure functions?

Comment: See my edits.  I'm not sure whether my additions concerning `&` fully address your question about pure functions... let me know.