# Unexpected behavior of Dataset

Tags: dataset

This code form documention of [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) in **ref/Dataset->Applicastions->Indexed Tables(Associations of Associations)**:

```
planets = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];
moonMass = planets["Earth", "Moons", "Moon", "Mass"];
planets[All, "Moons", Select[#Mass > moonMass/2 &] /* Keys]
```

[image]

But I cannot understand this behavior all the time.I this that `Keys` should act on the last result to get a outcome same with `Keys[planets[All,"Moons",Select[#Mass>moonMass/2&]]]`.I make example for simulate it.

```
dataset = Dataset[<|
   ld -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   le -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   lf -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   lg -> <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   lh -> <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   li -> <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>|>]
```

[image]

```
dataset[Select[#a < 4 &] /* f, "c"]
```

> f[<|ld -> {1}, le -> {2, 3}, lf -> {3}|>]
>   As we can see,the `f` act on the last result.If we want to get a result same to the documentation,the code should be:

```
dataset[Select[#a < 3 &] /* (Keys /@ # &)]
```

[image]

Do anyone agree this this opinion?

Comment: You might be interested in the _Long Answer_ section of [(98193)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98193/142) which discusses the action of ascending and descending operators.

Comment: @WReach That is a great reference. +1 here and there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For

```
Keys[planets[All,"Moons",Select[#Mass>moonMass/2&]]]
```

First `planets[All,"Moons",Select[#Mass>moonMass/2&]]` must be resolved before [`Keys`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html) can operate on this. The `planets` [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) returns a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) whose first level are the planet names as keys.  Therefore `Keys` returns the planet name keys.

For

```
dataset[Select[#a < 4 &] /* f, "c"]
```

You must first appreciate *ascending* and *descending* operators of [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) (read the *Details and Options* section). [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html) (`"c"` in this case) are *descending* operators. `f` is taken to be an *ascending* operator. `Query` does the following.

1. **Descend**

   1.1 `Select[#a < 3 &]` - This returns `dataset` with the rows filtered at level 1

   1.2 `"c"` - Get the `Values` of `Key` `"c"` at level 2 for these filtered rows
2. **Ascend**

   2.1 No further action at level 2

   2.2 `f` - At level 1 apply `f` to the results

For

```
dataset[Select[#a < 3 &] /* (Keys /@ # &)]
```

`Select` is *descending* and `(Keys /@ # &)` is *ascending*. `Select` filters the rows and then `Keys` is [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)ed onto the [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) of each row. Here, the value of each row is the [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) that defines the row. Therefore the column name keys are returned. I find it more intuitive to code `dataset[Select[#a < 3 &], Keys]` as it clearly shows what is happening at level 1 and level 2 of the `Dataset`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the dataset in the documentation has a different format than your example. They have an association as the value of the last key, you have a list as the value of the last key. If we modify your data as follows:

```
dataset = 
 Dataset[<|ld -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> <|"l" -> {1}|>|>, 
   le -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> <|"l" -> {2, 3}|>|>, 
   lf -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> <|"l" -> {3}|>|>, 
   lg -> <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> <|"l" -> {4, 5}|>|>, 
   lh -> <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> <|"l" -> {5, 6, 7}|>|>, 
   li -> <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> <|"l" -> {}|>|>|>]
```

then the following works

```
dataset[Select[#a < 4 &], "c", #l & /* f]
```

With your original dataset, the following code would produce the same result

```
f /@ dataset[Select[#a < 4 &], "c"]
```

[image]