# Getting slices of a nested Association via Query

Tags: associations, query

I'd like to get specific slices from a nested database-like `Association` through `Query`. Take for example this toy database of letters in different alphabets

```
db = <|"English" -> <|"Num" -> Range[26], "Letter" -> Alphabet[]|>, 
         "Greek" -> <|"Num" -> Range[24], "Letter" -> Alphabet["Greek"]|>, 
         "Russian" -> <|"Num" -> Range[33], "Letter" -> Alphabet["Russian"]|>|>;
```

Using `Query` one can find for instance the first entry for the english and greek alphabet

```
db // Query[{"English", "Greek"}, All, 1]
```

> <|"English" -> <|"Num" -> 1, "Letter" -> "a"|>,  "Greek" -> <|"Num" ->
>   1, "Letter" -> "α"|>|>

or only the letter entries

```
db // Query[{"English", "Greek"}, "Letter", 1]
```

> ```
> <|"English" -> "a", "Greek" -> "α"|>
> ```

What I'd like to obtain is a list of these slices using part specification e.g. the first three of these slices like in

```
Table[db // Query[{"English", "Greek"}, "Letter", n], {n, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {<|"English" -> "a", "Greek" -> "α"|>, 
>  <|"English" -> "b",  "Greek" -> "β"|>, 
>  <|"English" -> "c", "Greek" -> "γ"|>}
> ```

Is this possible using `Query` alone (without using `Query` multiple times)?

Comment: For those seeking to understand `Query`at a deeper level, take a look at [(98193)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98193/764).

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
db // Query[ Drop[ #, None, {3} ]& @* Transpose, 2, 1 ;; 3 ]
```

> {<|"English" -> "a", "Greek" -> "α"|>, <|"English" -> "b", 
>     "Greek" -> "β"|>, <|"English" -> "c", "Greek" -> "γ"|>}

Equivalently we could have written:

```
db // Query[ Transpose /* ( Drop[ #, None, {3} ]&), 2, 1 ;; 3 ]
```

or thinking positively (instead of dropping elements):

```
db // Query[ (1 ;; 2) /* Transpose, 2, 1;;3 ]
```

To understand how the queries work, we can take a look by using `Normal` as WReach has shown in his excellent post, that I have linked above. So:

```
Query[ (1 ;; 2) /* Transpose , 2, 1 ;; 3 ] // Normal
```

reveals

> GeneralUtilities`Slice[1;;2]/*GeneralUtilities`Slice[All,2,1;;3]/*GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose

Here `Slice` simply is an operator form of `Part`. So we can simulate the Query by doing:

```
db // RightComposition[
    #[[1;;2]] &,
    #[[ All, 2, 1 ;; 3]]&, (* or: Map[ #[[2, 1;; 3]]& ] *)
    GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose
]
```

Following WReach's suggestion, we have to think of a query as a sequence of

```
descending operations /* ascending operations
```

on each level of the expression starting with level 0. In the above case we have:

```
Query[

    (* descending   /* ascending *)

    #[[ 1;; 2]] &   /* AssociationTranspose, (* Level 0 *)
    Map[ #[[2]]& ]  /* Map[ Identity ],      (* Level 1 *)
    Map[ #[[1;;3]]& /* Map[ Identity ]       (* Level 2 *) 

]
```

Answer (score 6):

@gwr led me to try `Transpose` after the first subquery as an *ascending operator* (`/*`).

```
db // Query[{"English", "Greek"} /* Transpose, "Letter", 1 ;; 3]
```

> {<|"English" -> "a", "Greek" -> "α"|>, <|"English" -> "b", "Greek" ->
>   "β"|>, <|"English" -> "c", "Greek" -> "γ"|>}

**As far as I understand** the internal order of evaluation in this case it is something like this (with **->** indicating a *descending operator* and **<-** indicating an *ascending operator*)

> db **->** select the rows *"English"* and *"Greek"* **->** select the *"Letter"* column from the result of the previous subquery **->** take the parts *1* through *3* from the result of the previous subquery **<-** jump up the resulting association two levels from where the last subquery ended and apply transpose at this level.

**Edit:**

To get slices with multiple entries per row (not only the *`Letter`*-column) one has to apply `Transpose` as an *ascending operator* at the level of column selection as well.

```
db // Query[{"English", "Greek"} /* Transpose, {"Num","Letter"} /* Transpose, 1;;3]
```

> { 
>   <|"English" -> <|"Num" -> 1, "Letter" -> "a"|>, 
>     "Greek" -> <|"Num" -> 1, 
>       "Letter" -> "α"|>|>, <|"English" -> <|"Num" -> 2, 
>       "Letter" -> "b"|>, 
>     "Greek" -> <|"Num" -> 2, 
>       "Letter" -> "β"|>|>, <|"English" -> <|"Num" -> 3, 
>       "Letter" -> "c"|>, 
>     "Greek" -> <|"Num" -> 3, "Letter" -> "γ"|>|>}

Comment: Someone who is more knowledgeable in the inner workings of `Query`, please correct me if my last paragraph is wrong.

Comment: Note, that you will not need to take parts on the first level (there are only twoo), thus `db // Query[{"English", "Greek"} /* Transpose, Transpose, 1 ;; 3]` will do the job.

Comment: Your statement that the subquery `1;;3` will take parts 1 through 3 from the result of the previous subquery is not correct. On the deeper levels the descending operation will be effectively `Map[ #[[1;;3]]& ]` (cf. WReach's excellent post that I have linked),