# How does Query decide the order in which the functions are applied?

Tags: query, order

First of all I know that `Query` is a nice way to organize your functions that are applying at specific levels of an expression. But I don't understand the order in which they are applied.

Consider the following dataset as an example.

```
data={
    <|"field 1"->1,"field 2"->2,"field 3"->3|>,
    <|"field 1"->4,"field 2"->5,"field 3"->6|>,
    <|"field 1"->7,"field 2"->8,"field 3"->9|>
}
```

If I were to apply the following Query on this dataset:

```
Query[
    ReverseSortBy["field 3"],
    StringJoin[ToString/@{#"field 1",#"field 2"}]&
]@data
```

Then I get:

> {"78", "45", "12"}

This means that first the function `ReverseSortBy["field 3"]` is applied to the entire expression to reverse the order based on "field 3" and then on each sub level the function `StringJoin[ToString/@{#"field 1",#"field 2"}]&` is applied to get the joined values from the two fields.

Note the order of application cannot be the other way since if `StringJoin[ToString/@{#"field 1",#"field 2"}]&` is applied on each sub level then the association structure is lost and then `ReverseSortBy` will not be able to find the `Key` `"field 3"` by which to reverse the list of associations.

So following the same idea I add another function:

```
Query[
    ReverseSortBy["field 3"]@*Select[#"field 3">3&],
    StringJoin[ToString/@{#"field 1",#"field 2"}]&
]@data
```

The functions must be getting applied from outer to inwards but this fails! Since now magically the order of application has changed from inner to outer.

Note the `Map` allows me to move inner level function to outer level and thereby controlling the order precisely as follows to make the above `Query` work:

```
Query[
    Map[StringJoin[ToString/@{#"field 1",#"field 2"}]&]@*ReverseSortBy["field 3"]@*Select[#"field 3">3&]
]@data
```

I get

> {"78", "45"}

as expected! But why did the second Query changed the order of function application and failed? What are the rules governing function application order inside `Query`?

Comment: similar: [Struggling to understand Query](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98181/142).

Answer (score 11):

@Lee's answer shows how to circumvent the problem by using [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) (`/*`) instead of [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) (`@*`), but it does not explain why this works. I will try to explain the "Why" in this answer.

Let's first look at the original example and see how the order is decided. The following is based on the extensive documentation of [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html):

- `Query` differentiates between two types of operators: "Ascending" and "Descending". First, "descending" operators are applied starting from the outermost one, then "ascending" operators are applied starting from the innermost one:

  > - An "ascending" operator is applied after all subsequent operators have been applied to deeper levels. … [»](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html#385556269)
  > - A "descending" operator is applied to corresponding parts of the original dataset, before subsequent operators are applied at deeper levels. … [»](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html#890837316)
- "Descending" operators include everything that somehow selects parts of the structure (`"key"`, `i;;j`, `All`, `Select[…], …`), or rearranges it (`Sort`, `SortBy[…]`, …)
- Everything else is considered an "ascending" operator. In particular, this includes any unknown operators and custom functions.

With this, we understand why the first example works: As a "descending" operator, `ReverseSortBy[…]` is applied before the "ascending" operator `StringJoin[…]&`.

In the second case, the first operator is of the form `…@*…` or `Composition[…,…]`. Since this is not of any of the forms recognized as "descending" operator, both operators are "ascending". This means the inner one is applied first, followed by the outer one.

Now, why does `…/*…` (i.e. [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)) work? This is due to the special handling of `RightComposition` by `Query`. From the "Details & Options" section:

> - When one or more descending operators are composed with one or more ascending operators (e.g. `desc /* asc`), the descending part will be applied, then subsequent operators will be applied to deeper levels, and lastly the ascending part will be applied to the result. [»](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html#1750249543)

This means that `Query` recognizes `ReverseSortBy[…]/*Select[…]` as composition of two "descending" operators, which are therefore applied before the "ascending" operator. `Select[…]@*ReverseSortBy[…]` on the other hand is not recognized in an analogous way. Unfortunately, I don't know why it was implemented this way, I myself have stumbled over this asymmetry several times already.

Comment: Excellent explanation @Lukas Lang.

Answer (score 6):

Using [RightComposition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html?q=RightComposition) in the expression which fails will produce the result you are looking for:

```
data = {
<|"field 1" -> 1, "field 2" -> 2, "field 3" -> 3|>, 
<|"field 1" -> 4, "field 2" -> 5, "field 3" -> 6|>, 
<|"field 1" -> 7, "field 2" -> 8, "field 3" -> 9|>
};

Query[ReverseSortBy["field 3"] /* Select[#"field 3" > 3 &], 
  StringJoin[ToString /@ {#"field 1", #"field 2"}] &]@data
```

[image]

You can see the difference between `Composition` and `RightComposition` by viewing the compiled form of the Query with `Normal`:

```
Query[ReverseSortBy["field 3"] @* Select[#"field 3" > 3 &], 
  StringJoin[ToString /@ {#"field 1", #"field 2"}] &] // Normal

Query[Select[#"field 3" > 3 &] /* ReverseSortBy["field 3"], 
  StringJoin[ToString /@ {#"field 1", #"field 2"}] &] // Normal
```

[image]

The first expression fails when applied to `data` because the output of `Map` is a list of strings, whereas `Select` is expecting an `Association` with a key of "field 3".