# Ascending and descending in the context of the order of operations on Datasets

Tags: filtering, dataset, order

I did not understand the concepts **ascending** and **descending** in the context of the **order** of operations on Datasets. It is listed in the documentation, on Dataset's page and yet I did not understand. Perhaps a reference to a place that has a more detailed explanation of this topic will suffice. Thanks.

Comment: From the documentation "A descending operator is applied to corresponding parts of the original dataset, before subsequent operators are applied at deeper levels." So ascending an descending operators behavior depends on the order, the sequence in which the operators are involved.

Comment: also see [Struggling to understand Query](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98181/142)

Comment: Thank you WReach!!! your comment was very important for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll bite. Let's play with the "Planets" dataset, as it offers a great example of nesting.

```
planets = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]
```

[image]

## Descending operators

Part operators such as `All` and `"key"` are descending operators, which means that the next operator will be applied at a nested level. Compare:

```
planets[Length]
(* 8 *)
```

as we have 8 rows in our dataset. `Length` here is applied to the whole dataset.

In the next expression, `All` descends one level down, so now `Length` is applied individually to each row. Since every row of the above dataset is an association with three keys - `Mass`, `Radius`, and `Moons`, the result is 3 for every row:

```
planets[All, Length]
```

[image]

Let's keep descending. In the next expression, `"Moons"` descends one more level, into the list of individual planets, so now `Length` operates at this level and returns the number of moons per planet:

```
planets[All,"Moons",Length]
```

[image]

## Ascending operators

Any function, such as `Length` above, is ascending, which means that it does not descend and operates at the current level. However, one other important feature is that *an ascending operator is applied after all subsequent ascending and descending operators have been applied to deeper levels*.

Consider the difference between

```
planet[All,"Moons",Total]
```

which aggregates every parameter in `Moon` column with `Total`,

[image]

versus

```
planet[All, "Moons", Total, "Mass"]
```

Here, `Total` is applied *after* the following `"Mass"` descending operator selects just that column.

[image]

Comment: This brings me closer to understanding the distinction (+upvote).

Comment: Thank you for the compliment, Daniel, that means a lot coming from you!